# How to get facebook access token with oAuth 2.0?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I want to get Facebook access token using oAuth 2.0 protocol in c#.  I have AppId and AppSecret keys with me.  I googled a lot and found many articles regarding this. All the articles are describing getting an access token using an asp.net web application.  But I don't want to use asp.net.  I want to get it using C# console application.  When I login to my facebook account and go to the App section and then edit settings for that App. Then there comes an option to use graphAPI for that App. Graph API gives the access token.  But this whole process requires user intervention and logging into facebook account.  I want to automate this whole process with C# and oAuth 2.0.  Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Give this a try http://facebooksdk.net/

Comment: @AnveshSaxena I dont want to use facebook sdk.

Comment: You might want to then give this a look https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/. It shows how to perform server side login using PHP, but the basics remain the same. Just curious, why not go for SDK ?

Comment: You require web scrapping to simulate login and authenticate application process(This is violate TOS of facebook platform). Legally you must require a web browser to do the authentication process.